# Is this a dead pixel on LED panel?

Tags: led, dead-pixel

It can be seen on red blue and green backgrounds. I already looked for other questions. I am adding detailed images below about variations of backgrounds.

**White Background**
[image: White Background]

**Red Background**
[image]

**Green Background**
[image]

**Blue Background**
[image]

Comment: this is clearly 6 pixels and a bit. Because it's only affecting half of the green sub-pixel at the bottom left I am more inclined to say it might be a bit of dust or something?

Comment: How can i clear if it dust ?

Comment: not sure, wait for an LED expert to give a proper answer? btw I mean dust inside the panel not just on the outside. No idea how to clean it. And no idea if my idea is actually correct. Was it always like that or is it new?

Comment: It is new on panel.

Comment: Is the panel new? If so, return it. If it is not new it is unlikely you'll be able to do anything to fix it, regardless the specific underlying cause.

Comment: @music2myear Panel was 3 years old. Sadly i need to try clean it if i can. Thanks for information. Marked as solution ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for posting those images. They are well done and clear.

Whether this is a dead pixel or some obstruction under the glass, besides some basic physical manipulation, it is unlikely you can fix this.

If it was a dead pixel it would be stuck in a given state. The fact it is dim indicates this may not be a stuck pixel.

Assuming, then, that it is more likely to be something under the glass, you could try gently but firmly jarring the screen to try to dislodge the particle. I would NOT advise blowing air, as it is unlikely there is an air path into that part of the screen, and if there was you would be more likely to add MORE particles to the area than you would be to clear this bit out.

But, there is a significant chance you cannot remove this though. LCD panels are not designed to be user serviceable, not out of a desire on the manufacturer's part to enforce a disposable culture, but based on how they must be in order to work reliably. If the panel is new and under warranty, you should pursue that option. If it is not, you may need to simply replace it, if this issue is significant enough you cannot use it.